# Validar resposta na controller está dando erro

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Preciso validar a resposta no meu método na controller. Para isso eu preciso de um if. Por que  o método não considera o retorno dentro de um IF? Assim:

```
public JsonResult ValidaLogin(string _email, string _senha)
        {
            INETGLOBALEntities db = new INETGLOBALEntities();
            bool validalogin = false;

            EncriptyDecripty cripto = new EncriptyDecripty();

            string s = cripto.Encrypt(_senha);

              var  result_login = (from login in db.tbl_usuario
                                    where login.email == _email && login.senha_usuario == _senha
                                    select new { login.email, login.nm_usuario }).ToList();

             if(result_login.Count > 0)
                return Json(new { result_login }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Dá erro, dizendo que o método não possui um retorno. Como valido então?

Meu Ajax

```
function ValidaLogin() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Login/ValidaLogin',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ _email: $('#inputEmail').val(), _senha: $('#inputPassword').val() }),
        success: function (data) {

            $(window.document.location).attr('href', '/Pesquisa/Pesquisa');
        },
        error: function (error) {

            alert('Usuário ou senha digitados de forma incorreta.');
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dá erro porque realmente não possuis retorno caso a condição do `if` não se verifique. Uma função do tipo `JsonResult` fica sempre a espera de um tipo de retorno.
Faz:

```
if(result_login.Count > 0){
    return Json(new { result_login }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}else{
    return Json(JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Depois no javascript verificas se a variável `result_login` existe.

**EDIT:**

No teu caso fazes:

```
function ValidaLogin() {    
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Login/ValidaLogin',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ _email: $('#inputEmail').val(), _senha: $('#inputPassword').val() }),
        success: function (data) {
            if(data != null){//Dá um alert do data para ver o que retorna. Possivelmente até pode dar undefined
                $(window.document.location).attr('href', '/Pesquisa/Pesquisa');
            }else{
                alert('Usuário ou senha digitados de forma incorreta.')
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Fiz assim, CesarMiguel e não deu erro mesmo no controller(Era a falta do else), mas continua entrando no success do ajax, ou seja, redirecionando para outra página. Não deveria entrar na função error?

Comment: Então tens de manipular o success. Coloca o código do teu ajax

Comment: @pnet, resposta atualizada